# How to Filter data when input is NULL it will NOT add the query Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, filtering, laravel-livewire

i want to make Filtering data with Laravel 9 and Livewire. the goal is when input is `NULL` the query will not search the input.

```
$barangs = Barang::with('supplier', 'merk', 'kategori')
            ->where('supplier_id', $this->supplierID)->where('merk_id', $this->merkID)->where('kategori_id', $this->kategoriID)->get();
```

so, if the `$this->supplierID` is `NULL` it will be like this below

```
$barangs = Barang::with('supplier', 'merk', 'kategori')
            ->where('merk_id', $this->merkID)->where('kategori_id', $this->kategoriID)->get();
```

how to achieve that ? thankyou so much for the answer

Comment: This is what you need: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways

Traditional `if()`

```
$barangQuery = Barang::with('supplier', 'merk', 'kategori')
    ->where('merk_id', $this->merkID)
    ->where('kategori_id', $this->kategoriID);

if ($this->supplierID) {
    $barangQuery->where('supplier_id', $this->supplierID);
}

$barangs = $barangQuery->get();
```

The other solution is using `when()`

```
$barangs = Barang::with('supplier', 'merk', 'kategori')
    ->where('merk_id', $this->merkID)
    ->where('kategori_id', $this->kategoriID)
    ->when($this->supplierID, function ($query) {
        $query->where('supplier_id', $this->supplierID);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: i've been trying to use the second one, but i wonder why my input always showing null even when i input it. so after hide the select2 and use the regular select, it work! thank you. did you know why my select2 like that ?

Comment: not enough information to help you with that. What you can do is check the request via the network tab in the dev tools.